# How to boot CDLinux image with VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, terminal, virtualbox, boot

I'm not sure stackoverflow is the best place to ask this question but it is worth a try.

I am trying to launch **CDLinux**, which is a linux-based OS. I've installed it on a flashdrive using **Linux Live USB Creator**. I can either boot on it by restarting my computer or boot on it with VirtualBox. (I'm running Windows 7)

The problem is that when I try to boot on it (either ways) I am supposed to access a screen where I can select my language and then the OS should start.
But instead I have access to a command terminal.

Each line starts with `grub>`
If I type "boot" the output is `Error 8 : Kernel must be loaded before booting`
What should I do to be able to boot my CDLinux OS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the control is transfered to from BIOS to your kernel code, but the control is remain under the grub. What it means is that grub cant able to find the loadable kernel image. So what you need to do is that, you need to tell the grub where the valid kernel image is reside.

Please refer the grub manual to load the exact kernel image. EX

http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-rg-en-4/s1-grub-commands.html

Comment: Ok so it seems that the command I should run is   `kernel /path/to/kernel`. But I don't know what is the path and the kernel version (for example vmlinuz-2.4.21). Like I said I have burned the iso on a flash drive and I use virtualbox to to virtualize the key.